# What benefits has Spring RCP (or another RCP framework worth mentioning) over Eclipse RCP?

Tags: swing, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, spring-rcp

In 2005 I built some smaller applications using eclipse rcp and I found this framework very handy. Now I am back at rich client development and need to decide in staying with eclipse rcp or switch to something more state of the art(?). Because I also had contact to spring core in the past, I am very interested in using spring rcp as an alternative.

Has somebody already worked with both (Eclipse and Spring RCP or another RCP framework worth mentioning) and can objectively compare these?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

havenAs for Spring RCP, the latest release seems to be from 2009. So unless I am missing a migration to a bigger project, I'd consider it dead.

My experience with Netbeans is about three years old. I am using Eclispe RCP for the most part now. In my opinion Maven Integration with Netbeans worked easier than with Eclipse. Main difference is the the usage of Swing in Netbeans vs. SWT in Eclipse. But there is a SO question about that already: [Netbeans RCP vs Eclipse RCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003372/netbeans-rcp-vs-eclipse-rcp)

edit: looks like Valkyrie is based on the old Spring RCP. But I haven't used that technology, yet. http://cmadsen.github.io/Valkyrie-RCP/